# Does it mean that Memory usage of app is same as size of app

Tags: java, android

This is a conceptual doubt I have. Request some one to resolve my doubt. I have an app of size 4.5MB and I am calculating memory usage of processes in the app. I am getting each process memory usage as 16MB...

```
final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
rt.gc(); 
final double startSize = rt.totalMemory()-rt.freeMemory();
```

What I am getting is correct or wrong?Does it mean that Memory usage of app  is same as size of app?

Comment: probably means that when the app is running is utilizing 16megs of memory. that can go up and down

Comment: So you mean it is ok?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the app is the size of the APK. Once installed in the device, the size might increase based on your storage in Database and SharedPreferences.

But the Memory usage that you mentioned is different. This is the RAM memory that your app used while it's running. For, e.g, if you have loaded a 2MB image in an image view, then your memory usage of process will increase.

Comment: Ok so to understand it, I can say that memory usage is not related to size of the installed app. Memory usage can be greater or lesser than the size of the app.

Comment: Yes. Memory usage is the runtime memory. It increases and decreases in the lifetime of the app. If it gets too big, gc will be called to reduce it. That's why if you see in the 'Memory' of Android Monitor in Studio, you will see the graph rise and fall and then rise.